# Why was the design decision taken to use differing brackets?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have just started learning Angular2, and was wondering why the developers decided to use various different wrapper in he html?  For instance:

```
[(ngModel)]="some.property"

(click)="someMethod()"

[src]="some.property"
```

I'm sure there is a nice logical reason behind it, and I am aware that they're used for differing purposes, but at first glance it seems inconsistent and an unnecessary obstacle to overcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each syntax has its own goal.

**1) Event Binding**

This is a one way binding from **inner** to **outer** component. Called as `event`. The outer component will call the `someMethod` when the `click` event is triggered from the inner component, or from the current `tag`.

```
(click)="someMethod()"
```

Example: Here `button`'s click handler calls the `onClickMe()` function

```
@Component({
  selector: 'click-me',
  template: `
    <button (click)="onClickMe()">Click me!</button>
    {{clickMessage}}`
})
export class ClickMeComponent {
  clickMessage = '';

  onClickMe() {
    this.clickMessage = 'You are my hero!';
  }
}
```

**2) One way data binding**

This is a one way binding from the **outer** into **inner**. This will pass the `some.property` to the `src` property in the inner `component` or `tag`.

```
[src]="some.property"
```

Example. Here we bind to the **innerText property** the value of `name` property

```
<h1 [innerText]="name"></h1>
```

or

```
<h1>{{ name }}</h1>
```

**3) Two way data binding**

And this is a two way binding from **inner** to **outer** and **vice versa**. This will do the two things.

```
[(ngModel)]="some.property"
```

Example: Here `input`'s value will be updated when `username` will be updated. And aslo when we type another value into the input, the `username` will be updated. So here you get two way data bindings. And under the hood with [(ngModel)] it creates one-way and event-bindings. This lines

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name">

<p>Hello {{ name }}!</p>
```

are equal to

```
<input [value]="name" (input)="name = $event.target.value">

<p>Hello {{ name }}!</p>
```

For a deep knowledge you can look up in the [**documentation**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html)

Answer (score 2):

this relates to visibility and control of binding. square brackets is binding from parent to child.

normal brackets is binding child to parent using event callbacks

both is two way binding.

In angular1 I think there was a lot less control over directional binding.

you can bind from controller to view, etc. But I use the parent child component example for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

It makes total sense to use different brackets.

There are these three types you have mentioned.

1. Property Binding `[]`
2. Event Binding `()`
3. Two-Way Data Binding `[()]`

The property binding is used to bind properties to an html element.
So you can use this for every single property on an html element.
It is also used by the Angular Directives which you can use from the framework or build yourself.

```
<img [src]="anImageUrlInTheComponent">
<!-- or -->
<a [routerLink]="'/dashboard'">Dashboard</a>
```

The event binding is used to bind events like `click`, `mouseover` or `onSubmit` etc.
You can also make your own events on a component with the EventEmitters but this is another subject.

```
<button (click)="doSomething()">Do Something</button>
<!-- or -->
<form (onSubmit)="submitForm()">
    <!-- form content -->
</form>
```

The last is the Two-Way Data Binding used for instance in NgModel.
I recommend to read [this](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html) article about Two-Way Data Binding.

Hope this helps :D